Find the value of $|z_1 + z_2 + z_3|$
If $z_1,z_2,z_3$ are complex numbers such that $|z_1| = |z_2| = |z_3| = |\frac{1}{z_1} + \frac{1}{z_2} + \frac{1}{z_3}| = 1$ then find the value $|z_1 + z_2 + z_3|$
I had this problem in my exam and I attempted it halfway but couldn't figure it out, this is what I did:
\begin{aligned}
|z_1 + z_2 + z_3| ≤ |z_1| + |z_2| + |z_3| \\
= 1 + 1 + 1 \\
=3
\end{aligned}
With this I can find an upper bound to the answer but not the exact value
Also since the Cardinality of $z_1,z_2,z_3$ is 1, is this something to do with a unit circle in complex plane

since $|z_1| = 1$, $\frac{1}{z_1} = \bar{z_1}_{}$. Same for $z_2,z_3$, so $1 = |\frac{1}{z_1} + \frac{1}{z_2} + \frac{1}{z_3}| = |\bar{z_1}_{} + \bar{z_2}_{} + \bar{z_3}_{}| $
This is the conjugate of the answer though, and abs conjugate is the same

i got this from ur unit circle comment lol so ty for that

Write $z_1 = r_1 e^{i\theta_1}, z_2 = r_2 e^{i\theta_2}, z_3 = r_3 e^{i\theta_3}$. Then,
$$\begin{align}
|z_1| = |z_2| = |z_3| &= 1\\
\Rightarrow r_1 = r_2 = r_3 &= 1
\end{align}$$
Then using the next equation,
$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{1}{z_1} + \frac{1}{z_2} + \frac{1}{z_3} \right|^2 &= 1\\
\Rightarrow |e^{-i\theta_1} + e^{-i\theta_2} + e^{-i\theta_3}|^2 &= 1\\ 
\Rightarrow \left(e^{-i\theta_1} + e^{-i\theta_2} + e^{-i\theta_3}\right)^*\left(e^{-i\theta_1} + e^{-i\theta_2} + e^{-i\theta_3}\right)&= 1\\
\Rightarrow \left(e^{i\theta_1} + e^{i\theta_2} + e^{i\theta_3}\right)\left(e^{-i\theta_1} + e^{-i\theta_2} + e^{-i\theta_3}\right)&= 1
\end{align}$$
At the same time, observe that
$$\begin{align}
\left|z_1 + z_2 + z_3 \right|^2 &= |e^{i\theta_1} + e^{i\theta_2} + e^{i\theta_3}|^2\\ 
&= \left(e^{i\theta_1} + e^{i\theta_2} + e^{i\theta_3}\right)^*\left(e^{i\theta_1} + e^{i\theta_2} + e^{i\theta_3}\right)\\
&= \left(e^{-i\theta_1} + e^{-i\theta_2} + e^{-i\theta_3}\right)\left(e^{i\theta_1} + e^{i\theta_2} + e^{i\theta_3}\right)
\end{align}$$
It follows that $\left|z_1 + z_2 + z_3 \right| = 1$.

Can you please explain how you are changing $(e^{-i\theta_1 + e^{-i\theta_2 + e^{-i\theta_3})$ to $(e^{i\theta_1 + e^{i\theta_2 + e^{i\theta_3})$ ??

By taking the complex conjugate
